# Apostrophe and Javascript / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, apostrophe

Right now I have this for my javascript code

```
'title': '<?=$name?>',
```

The thing is, occasionally $name will have an apostrophe in it, and can have the code look something like this

```
'title': 'Bon Jovi It's My Life - Bon Jovi',
```

which essentially screws up the javascript.

Would I just do a mysql_real_escape_string on the $name? Wouldn't that leave slashes in the title when I go to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJson = {
       title: '<?php echo addslashes($somePHPVar) ?>'
    };
</script>
```

`addslashes` is the key. See [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

Comment: That does not deal with `</script>`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: What? If he's writing Javascript inside HTML, he has `<script>` tags. Fair enough, if it's a PHP-generated `.js` file, he may not. I included them only for completion. The PHP function is the point.

Comment: If his string contains '</script>' it will end the script tag even if it's inside a string. That's why json encoders usually escape forward slashes.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Ah I see what you mean. His question only dealt with the sort of characters that `addslashes` takes care of, but if he wants to completely escape anything then, yes, you're right, he needs more.

Answer (score 0):

use `str_replace()` before send the string to javascript

```
str_replace($name, ' ', '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()`. Never build JSON using string functions.

Comment: Why not? The entire point of JSON is that it's Javascript object notation compatible. That's what it is. I'd only encode into a JSON string for serialisation. There is no reason to do it here.

Comment: He does not need to use an object. It also does a good job for strings.

Comment: I think, he uses json actually, cause `'name': 'value'` syntax isn't possible in js except for object literals.